# Automatic updation of data table at

Tags: c#, winforms

In a window application I m feeling a data table at the time of page load and i have some buttons like Save and Display on the page.

When i save a new record it saved successfully but at the time of display it does't show the new added record because i feel the data table at page load which have no new added record.

The one way to display the new record is that i should fill data table again at Display button click. But it effects speed constraints.

Have any another suitable idea to display new added record.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

It depends upon the code you have written in button's handler. If the DataTable instance is already has been bind with the `UI` then you should have to add a `row` into that `DataTable` instance while saving it to the database.